# Element prototype as string

Tags: javascript

If it possible to create an `Element.prototype` as a string?

*For example :*

**instead of :**

```
Element.prototype.height = function() { return this.offsetHeight; };
```

**to write something like this :**

```
Element.prototype.height = Element.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: yes, and result is : undefined

Comment: Is `Element.offsetHeight` defined? Note that the two snippets are not equivalent. The first one gets `offsetHeight` from the *instance*, the second one from the constructor function. So, if `offsetHeight` is a property of the instance and determined during the initialization, you have to use a function to proxy that value through `height`.

Comment: `Element.prototype.height = Element.prototype.offsetHeight;` Element is a class (function) so probably it won't have `offsertHeight` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Element.prototype = {
        get height( ):{   return this.offsetHeight;   }
        constructor : Element
};
```

*Usage:*

```
new Element().height    //without parenthesis
```

More about, see [Object getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).